# Add Driver Option Disabled eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Please find the attached Screenshot. While adding database connection these fields are disabled. How can i enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the name/type in the first tab.

[image: eclipse driver select]

After you see on top message "Unable to locate ..........." then you can go to second tab

[image: database driver jar]

"Add Jar/zip" button is enabled.